# How to move cursor into text node and make it editable if there is no preexisting content using Range and Selection Objects?

Tags: javascript, dom, range, selection, contenteditable

I am trying to make text changes based on when the user clicks the "bold" button using the Range and Selection Objects. When the text node is empty, the range that I have set using `setStart()` and `setEnd()` seems to not be working because the cursor does not move into the text node, but rather stays at its initial text node that is already given within my `contenteditable` div. However, If I add some preexisting content to the text Node, the range is correct,the cursor moves into the newly-created text node, and the content is bold as well as my additional input. So how do I get the cursor to go into the text Node without any content? Thanks.

Here is a code snippet:

```
function setBold() {    
    let parent = document.querySelector('.current'); /*contenteditable parent element*/ 
    let sel = window.getSelection();
    let selRange = s.getRangeAt(0); 
    let bold = document.createElement('b'); 
    let range = document.createRange();
    /*if the node has content this solution works, but in this example it does not currently*/
    let node = document.createTextNode("");
    parent.appendChild(node);
    range.setStart(node,0);
    range.setEnd(node,node.length);
    range.surroundContents(bold);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
}
```

Comment: This is a non trivial problem, and there are many, rather in depth, approaches. Medium, Stack Overflow, Google Docs, Facebook, twitter, they all handle ranges with custom tracking. Depending on the sophistication of your design, you may either need to implement your own custom tool for tracking cursor position in the contentEditable space, or you may just go with the browser default which while broken everyone understands is broken.

Comment: I may have found a solution. Instead of leaving the content of the node as ```""```, I put the zero-width character in as a placeholder. So it would be ```document.createTextNode('\u200B')```. It seems to work fine, but is there any reason why not to use it?